# Caffeine cache metrics only report cache size but not hit/miss ratio with micrometer

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, micrometer, caffeine-cache

I'm using Caffeine cache for Java Spring Boot `com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:3.1.1`. This is my cache configuration class:

```java
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {
  
  @Bean
  public Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineConfig() {
    return Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(10000)
        .recordStats()
        .removalListener((key, value, removalCause) -> {
          // TODO: log
        });
  }

  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager(Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeine) {
    CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
    caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("AsyncTest.getStr");
    list.add("AsyncTest.getStr2");
    list.add("AsyncTest.getStr3");
    list.add("AsyncTest.getStr4");
    list.add("AsyncTest.getStr5");
    caffeineCacheManager.setCacheNames(list);
    return caffeineCacheManager;
  }
}
```

I also have test methods with `Cacheable` annotation like this:

```java
  @Cacheable("AsyncTest.getStr")
  public String getStr(int i) {
    return "abc";
  }
```

and finally I have a test controller which populates cache:

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      asyncTest.getStr(i);
    }
```

However, when I check Spring actuator metrics I only see one cache-related metric: size

```
        "myapp.cache.size": 250.0,
        "myapp.cache.size.tags": "{name=AsyncTest.getStr, cache=AsyncTest.getStr, cacheManager=cacheManager}",
```

However, why don't I see other metrics like `cache.gets`, `cache.puts` etc. as should be [provided](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/cache/CaffeineCacheMetrics.java) by Micrometer?

Answer (score 1):

The metrics you are seeing are the common `CacheManger` metrics. To get Caffeine specific ones, you'll need to `monitor` those caches as they are created.

I've not run this code, but subclassing the `CaffeineCacheManager` and hooking into the `createNativeCaffeineCache` should do the trick:

```java
public CacheManager cacheManager(Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeine, MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager(){
          protected com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache<Object, Object> createNativeCaffeineCache(String name) {
          return CaffeineCacheMetrics.monitor(meterRegistry, super.createNativeCaffeineCache(name), name);
      }

    };
    caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine);
}
```

There is likely a better way. But this *should* work.